How to present a Difference-in-Difference regression output using Rstudio?
How do I present a difference-in-differences regression output like the following in R?


TRY STARGAZER PACKAGE

In addition to stargazer, you can also try to use model summary package. I used to use stargazer, and stargazer is very good if you need just quick table, but model summary gives you more options and control over the table.
Quick example;
install.packages('modelsummary')
library(modelsummary)
mod <- lm(y ~ x, dat)
modelsummary(mod, output = "table.tex")

See the package manual for more details.

install.packages('stargazer')
library(stargazer)

x1 = rnorm(100)
x2 = x1 + rnorm(100)
y = 2*x1+3*x2
model = lm(y~x1+x2)

stargazer(model)

And if you are using the package 'fixest' for estimation (which is a good idea because it is fast if you have many fixed effects) then you can use the function table() as documented via this link
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fixest/versions/0.3.1/topics/etable
